# Pressing SHIFT interrupts holding down W in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, keyboard-events

I am making a roguelike in Pygame. I am trying to make my character move forward with either the W or the UP key. When SHIFT is held down, movement should be twice as fast. If I hold down SHIFT and then press W, the program works as it should, however, if I am holding down W, and the character is already moving forward, and then I press SHIFT, the character stops. This happens only occasionally, but it needs to be fixed.

```
    character_pos = [0,0]
    move_speed = 1
    mods = pygame.key.get_mods()
    if mods & KMOD_SHIFT:
        move_speed = 2
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_w] or key[pygame.K_UP]:
        w_count += move_speed
        if w_count == 20:
            w_count = 0
            if not is_wall(character_pos[0], character_pos[1]-1):
                character_pos[1] -= 1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `w_count` starts at 0 and is incremented in steps of *either* `1` or `2`, it will always pass `20` as it increases. But if it is incremented by a combination of `1`s and `2`s, it might go from `19` to `21`. Could that be the problem? Try changing `if w_count == 20` to `if w_count >= 20`.

Apologies if I have misunderstood your code, I'm not 100% clear on the purpose of the counter.

Comment: Thanks, that's it, no idea how I missed it. The purpose of the counter is that this is inside of the Pygame loop, which runs once per frame (30fps), the counter increments slowly so the character doesn't fly across the screen at lightspeed.